# Unable to return to next step if false

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Sorry I am very new in coding and appreciate if you give me some advice on my coding.

My intention for the coding is if the google sheet able to find "TOR": in column D & date in column I, if both values are in the list then help me to change the value of F but if the values are not in the list then help me to record at another page.

I encounter some issues which are if the values are in column D and I, then everything ok, but if the values don't exist in the list then it cannot run another step, I can't found what the reason.

Appreciate if someone can help me to check the coding and give me some advice.

```
function CheckTOR(){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
    var ws = ss.getSheetByName("RSS Route Plan");
    var lastRow = ws.getLastRow();
    var range = ws.getRange(1,2,lastRow,9);
    var values = range.getValues();
    for(var i =1; i < values.length; i++) {


    if(values[i][2] == "TOR"
      && values[i][7] == "30/06/20"){
      var rownumber = i;
      if(rownumber > -1){
     var CallRecord = ws.getRange(rownumber + 1, 8).getValue();   
     ws.getRange(rownumber + 1,8,1,1).setValue(CallRecord + 1);  


      } else {

         var ws1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet16");   
         ws1.getRange(1,1).setValue(1);    


      }
      }    
    }
```

Comment: Remove`rownumber` and use `i` instead. Use only one `if`. Combine all those conditions to one `if`

Comment: Thanks for the help, it solves my issue, Thanks

Comment: Consider adding a answer below in the answerbox. See [answer]

Answer (score 1):

The answer based on advice from TheMaster,

```
function CheckTOR(CRO,date){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
    var ws = ss.getSheetByName("RSS Route Plan");
    var lastRow = ws.getLastRow();
    var range = ws.getRange(1,2,lastRow,9);
    var values = range.getValues();
    for(var i =1; i < values.length; i++) {
        if(values[i][2] == "TOR" && values[i][7] == "10/06/20" && i > -1) {  
             var CallRecord = ws.getRange(i + 1, 8).getValue();   
             ws.getRange(i + 1,8,1,1).setValue(CallRecord + 1);  
        } 
    }
}
```